# Lizmap content filtering for different users and other

Tags: lizmap, filtering

I am absolute begginer with Lizmap.
It would be great if I could get some explanation so i am able to continue with Lizmap and my Qgis data web publishment project.

Can i setup content filtering in accordance to different user accounts/groups on lizmap web client . I basically would like that some of the gis data lying on Lizmap is accesible to all people using interent but all the gis (from a  Qgis project) data to some users.

Can I  define users groups based on their email and how? Is then some kind of user logIN available  on the   LizMap web client , in accordance to that?

Comment: You should ask a single question per "question" on stack exchange. You two questions are not related to each other.

Answer (score 2):

> Can i setup content filtering in accordance to different user accounts/groups on lizmap web client

Yes, there is user/groups in Lizmap Web Client.
You can use the internal Lizmap table for managing accounts and groups. Or you can also connect it to external LDAP or SAML.

The filtering can be done at different levels :

- folder level : if the repository must be displayed or not for some users/groups
- project level : if a project must be displayed or not for some users/groups
- layer level :

  - if a layer is visible or not
  - if a layer has editing capabilities or not
- feature level : within a layer, some features can be visible or not according to an attribute, or according to a spatial intersection.

  - same for edition at the feature level

See screenshot for spatial filtering for instance https://docs.lizmap.com/current/en/publish/lizmap_plugin/filtered_layers_login.html#id2

LDAP : https://docs.lizmap.com/current/en/install/ldap.html

SAML : https://github.com/jelix/saml-module